# get facebook access token is invalid

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-access-token

i can get access token from  this  link with some click :)

> http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

i retrived  access token is long and it work for

> graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token

and  other graph api

but when i get access token with this  URL it is  very short  and not work

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_tokenclient_id=MYID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbenbiddington.wordpress.com&client_secret=MYSECID&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=read_stream,manage_friendlists,read_mailbox,read_page_mailboxes

it dont work and  return

> {    "error": {
>         "type": "QueryParseException",
>         "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."    } }

but is some  case it work

Answer (score 0):

This is a VB.NET example - but I use this get get an access token for a user all the time, and have never received the response you are showing - so maybe this will help?

```
   Public Class FacebookAuthorization

    Private Shared Property BaseURL As String = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize"


    Public Shared Function GetAuthUrl(ByVal appID As String, ByVal redirectUrl As String, ByVal permissions As String) As String

        Return String.Format("{0}?client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&type=user_agent&scope={3}", BaseURL, appID, redirectUrl, permissions)

    End Function

End Class
```

EDIT:

The access_token you get back from this request can be used like so:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=XXXXXX - get's you their wall/timeline

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=XXXXXX - get's you their news feed

Comment: you can retrieve information with this  token in this  url ?
(4:30 PM) afshar: https://graph.facebook.com/SOME-ID/posts?method=GET&metadata=true&format=json&callback=___GraphExplorerAsyncCallback___&access_token= ???